# mongodb FindAndModify - update data

Tags: python, mongodb

I have this already in the MongoDB collections.

> { "_id" : ObjectId("4e677efce88c7f0718000000"), "ptbn" : "indl000000001", "tbucode" : "5649", "district" : "west", "dcode" : "110048", "tbu" : "super clinic", "state" : "delhi" }

I am unable to understand how to work with `FindAndModify` from MongoDb

I am working on MongoDb 1.8

I just want to modify the 'state' from delhi to goa, and 'district' from west to north.

How do I modify all entries EXCEPT 'ptbn' in Python-2.6

This is what I've tried so far:

```
     connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)
     db = connection.health
     tc = db.tc_basic

     basic = {'state' : state, 
              'district' : district,
              'Dcode' : Dcode, 
              'tbu' : tbu,
              'tbucode' : tbucode,
              'ptbn' : ptbn
              }

     tc.save(basic)
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need `findAndModify` for this. A simple `update()` will do the trick.

```
db.tc_basic.update({'_id':ObjectId("...")}, {'$set': {'state': 'goa', 'district': 'north'}})
```

For more details on what you can do with `update()` see: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating

Comment: To make this work with a form, just put the fields you want to change into a dict, and make that the value for the '$set' key above. For completeness I should mention that you should never trust field names supplied by the user. You don't want them to be able to set arbitrary fields. You don't have to worry about escaping the values though as long as they are strings or numbers.