# mongodb FindAndModify - update data

Tags: python, mongodb

I am using MongoDB 1.8 with python 2.6 and want to modify a 'value' ... dynamically ...

with reference to this link [mongodb FindAndModify - update data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338806/mongodb-findandmodify-update-data) the solution did not work for me.

The following is the line within my python script, to insert into MongoDb collections.

```
basic = {'state' : state, 'district' : district,'Dcode' : Dcode, 'tbu' : tbu,'tbucode' : tbucode, 'ptbn' : ptbn
              }
```

This is the MongoDb output.

> { "_id" : ObjectId("4e677efce88c7f0718000000"), "ptbn" :
>   "indl000000001", "tbucode" : "5649", "district" : "west", "dcode" :
>   "110048", "tbu" : "super clinic", "state" : "delhi" }

So the requirement is ... IF some user enters a new value in a web form OR a GUI, and wants to change ANY value OR a single value WITHOUT every time doing it from MongoDB command terminal... how will the value be changed in the Collection / document ?

> db.tc_basic.update({'_id':ObjectId("...")}, {'$set': {'state': 'goa',
>   'district': 'north'}})

Above requires me to do it manually ... i Need to do it dynamically.... by the python script.

As I will not know the ObjectID in every DB installed in different computers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's a new object then you have to `insert`.

If the object already exists and the user modifies it then you've already retrieved the object(s) from the collection so you knew its `ObjectId`. Put it in the HTML form as hidden field so you will know which object to update.